# Diagonalized matrix question?

Tags: matrices

So I have the matrix 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 3
 \end{pmatrix}
I have to find a diagonalized matrix for this matrix.So I have found the eigenvalues, which are 1 2 3,how do I find now the diagonalized matrix?

Comment: diagonalized matrix :$$\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 3
 \end{matrix}$$

Comment: Not the diagonal form of this matrix,find a diagonalized matrix for this matrix.

Comment: Maisam wrote it because of the eigenvalues. If a matrix is diagonalizable, then the diagonal will contain exactly the eigenvalues.

Comment: Note that if the characteristic polynomial splits, and if the eigenvalues are pairwise distinct, then the matrix is automatically diagonalizable. And its "diagonalized form" is the diagonal made of these eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

You should get an Eigensystem as follows:

$$\lambda_1 = 3, v_1 = (0, 0, 1)$$

$$\lambda_2 = 2, v_2 = (-1, -1, 1)$$

$$\lambda_3 = 1, v_3 = (-2, 0, 1)$$

Next, we can write the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) as:

$$A = P J P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 1& 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0& 3\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

What do you notice about $J$? What is it made from?

What do you notice about the columns of $P$? What is it made from?

Regards

Comment: Similar matrices. +

Answer (score 0):

Find the eigenvectors corresponding to your eigenvalues and use those to diagonalise your matrix. Say, your matrix is $A$ and $(\lambda_i,u_i)$ are your eigenpairs, i.e. $Au_i = \lambda_i u_i$ then you have 
$AU=\Lambda U$ with $U=[u_1, u_2, \ldots]$ and $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots)$ and thus the similiarity transform
$$U^{-1}AU=\Lambda$$
diagonalises your matrix.

Comment: for the eigen value 2, will the vector  look like (1 1 0)  can you check that for me please?

Comment: $(1,1,0)$ is mapped to the sum of the first and the second column, that is $(2,2,1)$ which is *not parallel* to $(1,1,0)$, so is not an eigenvector.